# MDX query in SSAS calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, mdx-query

I tried the `MDX` Query in SQL correctly
But I will insert that query in the **VisualStudio(SSAS)** in the Calculated Members section, but the process time will be faulty

```
Select 
[Measures].[Fact Student Status Count]on columns
From [Cube_REG_Amozesh DW]
Where ( [Dim Student Status].[Student Status Key].[Student Status Key]-[Dim Student Status].[Student Status Key].&[0])
```

I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     MdxScript(Cube_REG_Amozesh DW) (2, 5) Parser: The syntax for
>   'Select' is incorrect. (CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[RegSt]  AS
>   Select   [Measures].[Fact Student Status Count]on columns from
>   [Cube_REG_Amozesh DW] where ( [Dim Student Status].[Student Status
>   Key].[Student Status Key]-[Dim Student Status].[Student Status
>   Key].&[0]), DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'شاخص'  ; ).         0

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish? What is supposed to be contained in the RegSt set? Is that basically the set in the where clause?

Comment: i want a count of records from one special fact except one special member whit X value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its worked:

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].RegST
     AS [Measures].[Fact Student Status Count]-([Measures].[Fact Student Status Count],[Dim Student Status].[Student Status Key].&[0])

Comment: type in script view

Comment: You should not have added that as answer, since you have used the script i provided, you should have marked mine as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your query, this is what you should be putting in Calculated measure

```
Sum({[Dim Student Status].[Student Status Key].[Student Status Key]-[Dim Student Status].[Student Status Key].&[0]},[Measures].[Fact Student Status Count]).
```

Plus make sure you uses Calculated measure not Set

Comment: Thanks, but what is the point that end of this query is used, is this correct?

Comment: Sorry i did not understand, can you repeat

Comment: is your mean :     with member Measures.RegST as
( Sum({[Dim Student Status].[Student Status Key].[Student Status Key]-[Dim Student Status].[Student Status Key].&[0]},[Measures].[Fact Student Status Count])) 
select 
Measures.RegST on columns
from [DSV_REG_Amozesh DW]????  type this query in Calculated Member